# Width of inline-block container never exceeds first line if floated div is present

Tags: html, css

I have an `inline-block` container that contains a floated div and some text that is supposed to wrap around the floated div. However, the container's width seems to be set by however long the first line is, up to the first line break. Every line of text after that never increases the width of the container any more.

Now when I either change the container to `display: block` or remove the floated div, everything works as expected. The container just grows with the text as needed. But as soon as both conditions exist, the container just won't grow past the width of the first line of text.

Here is a simple example:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="float"></div>
  Lorem ipsum<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.float {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  
  float: left;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle of the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/ckLvqhex/

And here is a JSFiddle of what I'm trying to achieve, except that the container here is `display: block` and thus doesn't shrink to fit the content:

https://jsfiddle.net/ckLvqhex/1/

How do I achieve the desired result?

### Edit

I've added a slider to my JS Fiddle example to modify the width of the floated div. What that shows is that as the width increases, the container at first doesn't grow but instead just makes the second line of text wrap. So the floated div just takes up more of the width of the container, but doesn't add to its overall width.

But: As soon as the end of the *first* line is "reached" the container doesn't compress the text any further and instead just starts increasing its overall width.

See for yourself:
https://jsfiddle.net/av6egboj/

This is further exemplified in this modified JS Fiddle where the first line of text is the longest. No matter how much the width of the floated div changes, not text ever gets wrapped. **This is the expected behavior.**

https://jsfiddle.net/p4hamtbe/

So why does this problem only occur, when the first line of text is not the longest line of text?

Comment: use dispaly:table

Comment: @Temani Afif: Still doesn't wrap the text correctly.

Comment: The width is not determined by the first line. It's determined by the longest line, up to the available width from the container, as if the float wasn't there. So when a non-zero width float is included, some of the text from the longest line, assuming it's adjacent to the float, (and possibly other lines) will wrap. Having said that, I don't think there's any way in CSS to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Alohci: So a floated non-zero block element inside an inline-block container doesn't contribute to the container's width? It just kinda ... Eats away at the width? Weird stuff.

Comment: @Alohci I just updated my question with two extra examples where the width of the floated div can be modified. The length of the first line definitely plays a role, because the first line never wraps.

Comment: You are right. The float is clearly participating the calculation of the preferred width of the first line. I don't know why it should be doing so right now.

Answer (score 0):

To stop text from wrapping, you can use the css property: `white-space: nowrap`. However, that will make the text extend outside the div rather than having the div extend to fit the text. This is due to the usage of

```
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
```

By removing them, the div works perfectly but removes the black div on the side.

This is where I'm confused. If the point is to have the black div on the left, then using simple html with bootstrap grid system is more than enough:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssSO.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container" style="display: inline-block;">
      <div class="test row" style="width: fit-content; height: fit-content;">
        <div class="col-2 float" style="background-color: black;"></div>
        <div class="col-10" style="white-space: nowrap;">
          Lorem ipsum<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
      </div>
   
    </div>
     
</body>

</html>
```

With this css:

```
.test {
border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

That will give you the expected output that you presented while using inline-block property.

However, considering this is a dummy example, I might be missing your point completely in which case the only advice I have is to avoid using width and height to create div columns and use bootstrap or similar properties instead.

Comment: Sorry but a bootstrap grid seems unnecessarily complicated for what I'm trying to achieve. The content consists of a fixed size div (hence the 60px wide and tall box) and text that needs to flow normally around it.

Comment: then why don't you just set the contianer width to fit the content exactly? I don't think there's a way to make the div size relative to the cotent when you're setting exact dimensions for one of the divs inside it

Comment: @ Miss Skooter: In my original example the div size IS relative to the content though, the text just wraps in an unexpected way. This is exactly what display: inline-block is for, no?

Comment: that's fair to be honest, can't argue with it. However, what seems to be causing an issue in everything I've tried is the 60px width and height and it always works correctly when I remove them :/